# What does "suck society under" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> And in the Philippines (which holds ASEANs rotating chair in 2017) under the irascible president, Rodrigo Duterte, a vigilante crusade against drug-dealers will threaten to **suck society under**.

I can't find the definition.

source: http://www.theworldin.com/edition/2017/article/12612/asean-way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your title is misleading due to a different word order than from the quote!

Basically, Duterte means that a vigilante crusade would be behaviour not expected of a civilised society.

Another way of saying **suck under** would be **drag down**, or that society would be **stooping to a low level**.

'Suck under' is sort of a metaphor - think of a whirlpool or a quagmire - anything that gets in it will be 'sucked' down - pulled down.

Comment: Not sure how you have arrived at "Duterte means", though your explanation of "suck under" as a whirlpool or quagmire is good.

Comment: Rodrigo Duterte is the president of the Philippines - I was referring to him by name.

Comment: But he isn't making the statement. How are you understanding **under**?

Comment: Apologies, I misread it - I thought it was a quote from Duterte. I understand the use of 'under' here.

Comment: I thought you might be understanding **under** to mean something like **per**, which might explain your reading of the passage.